# Relación Investigador-Director-CENTRO

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una base de datos sobre un grupo de investigadores los cuales quieren almacenar los artículos escritos por este, de los cual se busca guardar los autores del mismo.

Mi problema surge cuando quiero crear y relacionar las tablas `DIRECTOR` del centro, `CENTRO` e `INVESTIGADOR`, ya que quiero dejar especificado que un *Director* puede ser o no un *Investigador* y, si es un *director*, dejar indicado el *Centro* que dirige.

¿Cómo realizo las relaciones o que tablas tengo que crear?

Estas son las condiciones:

- Un director dirige un centro de investigación;
- Un centro de investigación posee varios investigadores (de momento hay 3 tablas `INVESTIGADOR`, `CENTRO` Y `DIRECTOR`).

Mi duda surge en cómo puedo especificar que un director puede ser o no un investigador, porque si hago la relación Director 1 - 1 Centro 1 - N Investigador, Director no es Investigador.

Comment: Por favor, plantea tus dudas, muestra tu avance, etc. no pretendas que te hagan el trabajo.

Comment: Buenas, antes de todo, gracias por responder.

Ahora bien, no entiendo muy bien lo que solicitas, creí que la duda se entendía... Pero en caso que no, ¿necesitas ver código o el diagrama ER?

Por si acaso vuelvo a plantear la duda: Un director dirige un centro de investigación; Un centro de investigación posee varios investigadores (de momento hay 3 tablas INVESTIGADOR, CENTRO Y DIRECTOR). Mi duda surge en como puedo especificar que un director puede ser o no un investigador, porque si hago la relación Director 1 - 1 Centro 1 - N Investigador, Director no es investigador.

Comment: Tal como te indican en la _no-respuesta_, debes mostrar lo que has intentado y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. [es.so] no es un sitio de orientaciones ni de tutoriales: se responde a preguntas _concretas_.

Comment: La tabla DIRECTOR puede que te esté sobrando. En la tabla CENTRO deberías crear un campo "director" el cual es fk de la tabla INVESTIGADORES (o sea ahí guardas la id del investigador). Esto siempre y cuando un director siempre sea un investigador, caso contrario deberías crear algo como una tabla PERSONAS